# Safe way to rename GitHub repository to the name of one I just deleted?

Tags: github, rename

I had 2 repos on Github: "RepoName" and "RepoName_old". I thought I was going to rebuild my project but changed my mind and have been improving "RepoName_old" ever since. I deleted "RepoName".

If I rename "RepoName_old" to "RepoName" (the deleted repository), will something go horribly wrong? The official documentation warns against trying to pull from a branch associated with the old name...I guess that's a different thing...will GitHub Desktop acknowledge the new name after I make the change?

I have terrible experience mismanaging my git repositories and I want to avoid another setback by being informed and careful.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Desktop is a local tool which should reflect the changes done on GitHub.

On GitHub side, if you have deleted RemoName, you should be able to rename "RepoName_old" to `RepoName`.
Check first that it works on `github.com`.

Then try and clone it in command line, and, [with GitHub Desktop, add it from your local folder](https://help.github.com/en/desktop/contributing-to-projects/adding-a-repository-from-your-local-computer-to-github-desktop). That should force GitHub Desktop to recognize `RepoName` with its new `origin` URL.